# Can I use PubNub instead of DirectLine with BotBuilder?

Tags: azure, pubnub, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

Building a productivity chatbot. Hosting it on Heroku. Since I want to have very minimal dependency on Azure, I want to avoid directline APIs. Is it possible to use PubNub instead? Any insights / examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible. This question may get flagged for not being "technical" so I  recommend deleting it and contacting [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) directly to discuss your use case in more detail. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## Building a Chatbot

You can build a chatbot with PubNub instead of DirectLine with BotBuilder.  The following shows you how to build a chatbot using serverless techniques.  The example also includes voice recognition using Google's voice API.  So it's just a step up from what you're asking.  You can include or exclude the [voice recognition technology used](https://github.com/stephenlb/spoken).

[image: Build a Chatbot]

> Walkthrough: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-an-80s-chatbot-with-an-npm-package/
>
> Try it live: https://stephenlb.github.io/artificial/
>
> GitHub: https://github.com/stephenlb/artificial

Comment: Thanks. I am using this https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder.  As I can handle my bot's flow. ( Much like an IVR). Using Dialogflow for AI /intent recognition.  I was wondering if I could skip this:  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS so that we could save some $$.  The serverless approach is not allowed in my use case.